# Неправильная работа модуля keyboard

Tags: python, клавиатура, pyautogui, python-keyboard

Проблема в том что все работает только с квадратными скобками, при этом внутри них ставиться }

Код:

```
import pyautogui

def auto(key):
    if key == '(':
        keyboard.write(')')
        pyautogui.press('left')
    elif key == '[':
        keyboard.write(']')
        pyautogui.press('left')
    elif key == '{':
        keyboard.write('}')
        pyautogui.press('left')
    elif key == '<':
        keyboard.write('>')
        pyautogui.press('left')
    elif key == '"':
        keyboard.write('"')
        pyautogui.press('left')
    elif key == "'":
        keyboard.write("'")
        pyautogui.press('left')

keyboard.add_hotkey('(', auto, args=('(',))
keyboard.add_hotkey('[', auto, args=('[',))
keyboard.add_hotkey('{', auto, args=('{',))
keyboard.add_hotkey('<', auto, args=('<',))
keyboard.add_hotkey('"', auto, args=('"',))
keyboard.add_hotkey("'", auto, args=("'",))


keyboard.wait()
```